# read data value from computed property

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to access the value of "ts" within the computed property so I can (eventually) return a different class according to its value. But I just can't get the value of "ts".

```
     <div id="example">

        <div v-for=" alerte in alertes" v-bind:class=bgcoul>
         {{alerte.text}}   {{alerte.ts}}
        </div>

    </div>


    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#example',
        data : {
          alertes:[ 
            {text: "qeq2", ts: '0'},
            {text: "qeq3", ts: '5'},
            {text: "qeq3", ts: '15'}
        ]
      },
         computed: {
            bgcoul: function () {
              console.log(this.ts);
              return { };
            }
         }
});
```

console.log(this.ts) only gives "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the ts value as parameter and use a method, see the code snippet below

```js
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#example',
        data : {
          alertes:[ 
            {text: "qeq2", ts: '0'},
            {text: "qeq3", ts: '5'},
            {text: "qeq3", ts: '15'}
        ]
      },
         methods: {
            bgcoul: function (ts) {
              console.log(ts);
              return { };
            }
         }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
     <div id="example">

        <div v-for=" alerte in alertes" v-bind:class="bgcoul(alerte.ts)">
         {{alerte.text}}   {{alerte.ts}}
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.ts` don't exist. `this.alertes` is a array of objects where each object has `ts` property.

```
computed: {
  bgcoul: function () {
    this.alertes.forEach(alert => console.log(alert.ts) )
    return { };
  }
}
```